# Formula based of Sheet Name

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to make the value of the formula is based on sheet name.

So if I have a cell with formula =**A!B..**, when I changed the sheet name to **7** the value of the formula above is changed to **=A!B7**, then changed the sheet name to **9** the formula changed to **=A!B9**.

Is it possible? thx

Answer (score 1):

you could try using CELL to reference thwe filename and MID to extract the sheet name:

```
="A!B"&MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

Comment: I got error when I use the above formula. I tried to change the , with ; then A1 with $A$1 but no luck.

Comment: @Oky The file has to be a saved workbook for it to work